# dropping random item based on chance

Tags: math, random

so Im making this game and I want to drop random items, this is what I used to do

if(Math.random() > 0.5) //%50 percent chance

{//code here
}

the problem with this method is I will keep adding more and more items to the game, so I want to create more dynamic way, because each time I add an Item I will need to re-type the whole function... not only adding one more if-else statement, but I need to change all the chances in all if statements(the total sum should be 100 in all)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to add a lot of items to an array and possibly drop them later.  Maybe try writing a function called "randomDrop" that accepts the array that contains the items, the index of the item that might be dropped, and the probability of dropping it.

For example, in pseudo code,

```
define randomDrop(myItems, itemIndex, dropProbability) {
    if ( Math.random() < dropProbability ) {
        myItems.remove(itemIndex);
    }
}
```

Then you can call this function wherever it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first random number to determine if an item is dropped and the second random number to determine how valuable the drop is.

```
// Drop occurred
if(Math.random() > 0.5)
{    
  var secondRandom = Math.Random();
  //something super valuable
  if(secondRandom  > 0.95)
  { ...  }

  //something less valuable
  else if(secondRandom  > 0.50)
  { ...  } 

  //least valuable
  else 
  { ...  }
}
```